# How to fill partially Excel table from Javascript task pane application

Tags: ms-office, excel-2013, office-addins, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I have an Excel table with 7 columns with data and 6 calculated columns. The table is connected with 3 charts.

A task pane add-in is used to get some parameters, implement some security (Bearer Token) and get the data. The query returns different number of rows for different parameters.

Because of this, I cannot use a range and have to use `Office.TableData`.

On samples like [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JS-ExternalDataGitHub) the table is destroyed every time and created again, which I cannot use, because the Excel workbook is used as template, and I do not know, what for connection this table has.

With bindings and `TableData` is possible to use different number of rows, but not to update the data partially.

These are the methods I have tried without success: `addFromNamedItemAsync`, `deleteAllDataValuesAsync`, `addRowsAsync`, `setSelectedDataAsync`.

I think, that it should be possible, because of the way how Excel Workbook Queries work. But how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though i dont have answer to your question but if you are not able to find answer to question related to office-add-in you should ask that question on social msdn forum. I got my answer from there. You can check my asked question related to office-add-in

Comment: OK, I did it. Why I ask here? When you go on ["Office Dev Center"](http://dev.office.com/) and you click on "Connect with us" you will be redirected to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office"

Comment: My [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a60c2199-929f-4dc7-a32d-8ba0afc3dc85/how-to-fill-partially-excel-table-from-javascript-task-pane-application?forum=appsforoffice#afe75a95-b01d-443d-9947-61fa9ae5bd69) in the msdn forum. I will post the response here, when is ready.

Comment: Yes, you have posted your question at right place, and as i can see you are reaching toward your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the latest version of the Excel JavaScript APIs (available in Office 2016 and Office365), which have more methods to use with tables: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/table

On the table, you could get the range and then get cells using offsets, for example:
`var range = table.getRange().getCell(1,1);`
There is also the `TableRowCollection` that allows you to retrieve specific rows and again, you could get subsets of it using `getCell`, or a combination of `getCell` along with `getIntersection` if you need to get a specific subrange.

Comment: I do not want to get data, but put data in the table with dynamic row count (table grow/shrink).

Comment: @Mottor In that case you can use the `TableRowCollection.Add(...)` method, which will allow you to add rows, or if you need to get a certain row, retrieve it from the TableRowCollection and modify it's values or delete that individual row using the `TableRow.delete()`.

Comment: And how this solves the problem with calculated columns?

Comment: @Mottor Once you've added your row, you can get the range of that row (`TableRow.getRange()`) and update the formulas (using either `Range.Formulas` or `Range.FormulasR1C1` so that you can set the formulas for the columns of the new row where you need to have calculated values in.

Comment: of course  I know this. The question is that this is common scenario and should be possible to automate it. Power Query does it (without growing). It will be faster to write it in C++ (as Microsoft API)  as in Javascript.

Comment: Try this (assume 3rd col has formula already in it):
`var newData = [[123,456], [111,222], [444,555]];
var ctx = new Excel.RequestContext();
var table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem("Table1");
var tableRows = table.rows;
ctx.load(tableRows);
ctx.sync()
.then(function(){
 if(tableRows.count > newData.length)
 {
  for(var i=newData.length-1;i<tableRows.count-1;i++){
   tableRows.getItemAt(i).delete();
  }
 }
 table.getDataBodyRange().getCell(0,0).getBoundingRect(table.getDataBodyRange().getCell(newData.length-1, newData[0].length-1)).values = newData;
 return ctx.sync();
})`